# Prevent Material UI Textfield background change color from editing

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, background, textfield, background-color

I am using '@material-ui/core: ^4.12.3' and working with Textfield component.

I have 1 text field:

[image]

After edit, text field back ground color is change from white to #E8F0FE:

[image]

How I can prevent changing color after editing the field? Any suggestion is really meaningful to me!

My Text field:

```
<TextField
      {...field}
      value={displayValue ?? field.value}
      onChange={handleChange}
      label={label}
      placeholder={isFocused ? placeholder : undefined}
      error={invalid}
      helperText={invalid && error}
      disabled={disabled}
      onFocus={handleFocus}
      onBlur={handleBlur}
      multiline={multiline}
      InputProps={{
        classes: {
          input: className
        },
        disableUnderline: disableUnderline,
        inputComponent: inputComponent
      }}
      InputLabelProps={{
        shrink: true,
        style: {
          fontSize: '15px',
          ...labelStyle
        },
        classes: {
          shrink: classes.inputLabel
        }
      }}
      inputProps={{
        'aria-label': label
      }}
      FormHelperTextProps={{
        style: {
          ...helperTextStyle
        }
      }}
      {...rest}
    />
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You have to override it's default CSS styles by using **makeStyles**.

I have written this code.

```
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  textFieldStyle: {
    "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
      "&.Mui-focused fieldset": {
        borderColor: "red",
      },
    },
  },
}));

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <>
      <TextField
        fullWidth
        variant="outlined"
        className={classes.textFieldStyle}
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have applied red border after TextField is being focused, you can add more CSS there and can change it according to your requirement.

You can try this code and let me know, if you have any issues.

Comment: FYI, I have updated the code and it's perfectly working in my case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have tried this way, but seem likes it doesn't work with my case. I will try the similar way as I think I use wrong its key name.